# How to I force a better execution plan when the database is forcing a join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, query-performance

I am optimizing a query on SQL Server 2005. I have a simple query against `mytable` that has about 2 million rows:

```
SELECT id, num
FROM mytable
WHERE t_id = 587
```

The `id` field is the Primary Key (clustered index) and there exists a non-clustered index on the `t_id` field.

The query plan for the above query is including both a Clustered Index Seek and an Index Seek, then it's executing a Nested Loop (Inner Join) to combine the results. The STATISTICS IO is showing 3325 page reads.

If I change the query to just the following, the server is only executing 6 Page Reads and only a single Index Seek with no join:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE t_id = 587
```

I have tried adding an index on the `num` column, and an index on both `num` and `tid`. Neither index was selected by the server.

I'm looking to reduce the number of page reads but still retrieve the `id` and `num` columns.

Comment: 2005?  Seriously?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN & STATISTICS results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following index should be optimal:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON MyTable (t_id)
INCLUDE (num)
```

I cannot remember if INCLUDEd columns were valid syntax in 2005, you may have to use:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON MyTable (t_id, num)
```

The [id] column will be included in the index as it is the clustered key.

Comment: I don't see how this is optimal. It still needs to select `id`.

Comment: The clustered index is on [id], which is included in all indexes automaticlly.

Comment: That still means 2 index searches and a join.

Comment: Ben, the first answer that MJH provided (with the ```INCLUDE``` clause) did exactly what I needed, and worked on SQL Server 2005. My query now executes as a single Index Seek with 6 reads. Perfection.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal index would be on `(t_id, num, id)`.

The reason your query is probably one that bad side is because multiple rows are being selected.  I wonder if rephrasing the query like this would improve performance:

```
SELECT t.id, t.num
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM my_table t2
              WHERE t2.t_id = 587 AND t2.id = t.id
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets clarify the problem and then discuss on the solutions to improve it:

You have a table(lets call it `tblTest1` and contains 2M records) with a Clustered Index on `id` and a Non Clustered Index on `t_id`, and you are going to query the data which filters the data using Non Clustered Index and getting the `id` and `num` columns.

So SQL server will use the Non Clustered Index to filter the data(`t_id=587`), but after filtering the data SQL server needs to get the values stored in `id` and `num` columns. Apparently because you have Clustered index then SQL server will use this index to obtain the data stored in `id` and `num` columns. This happens because leafs in the Non clustered index's tree contains the Clustered index's value, this is why you see the Key Lookup operator in the execution plan. In fact SQL Server uses the `Index seek(NonCluster)` to find the `t_id=587` and then uses the `Key Lookup` to get the `num` data!(SQL Server will not use this operator to get the value stored in `id` column, because your have a Clustered index and the leafs in NonClustered Index contains the Clustered Index's value).

[image]

Referred to the above-mentioned screenshot, when we have `Index Seek(NonClustred)` and a `Key Lookup`, SQL Server needs a `Nested Loop Join` operator to get the data in `num` column using the `Index Seek(Nonclustered)` operator. In fact in this stage SQL Server has two separate sets: one is the results obtained from Nonclustered Index tree and the other is data inside Clustered Index tree.

Based on this story, the problem is clear! What will happen if we say to SQL server, not to do a Key Lookup? this will cause the SQL Server to execute the query using a shorter way(No need to Key Lookup and apparently no need to the Nested loop join! ).

To achieve this, we need to `INCLUDE` the `num` column inside the NonClustered index's tree, so in this case the leaf of this index will contains the `id` column's data and also the `num` column's data! Clearly when we say the SQL Server to find a data using NonClustred Index and return the `id` and `num` columns, it will not need to do a Key Lookup!

Finally what we need to do, is to `INCLUDE` the `num` in NonClustered Index! Thanks to [@MJH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763219/1666800)'s answer:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON tblTest1 (t_id)
INCLUDE (num)
```

[image]

Luckily, SQL Server 2005 provided a new feature for NonClustered indexes, the ability to include additional, non-key columns in the leaf level of the NonClustered indexes!

Read more:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017

But what will happens if we write the query like this?

```
SELECT id, num
FROM tblTest1 AS t1
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblTest1 t2
              WHERE t2.t_id = 587 AND t2.id = t1.id
             )
```

This is a great approach, but lets see the execution plan:

[image]

Clearly, SQL server needs to do a Index seek(NonClustered) to find the t_id=587 and then obtain the data from Clustered Index using Clustered Index Seek. In this case we will not get any notable performance improvement.

**Note:** When you are using Indexes, you need to have an appropriate plan to maintain them. As the indexes get fragmented, their impact on the query performance will be decreased and you might face performance problems after a while! You need to have an appropriate plan to Reorganize and Rebuild them, when they get fragmented!

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Vahid, excellent explanation. When I posed the original question I knew nothing about ```INCLUDE``` and storing additional fields in the index. After reading the solution provided by @MJH the answer was obvious and I've already deployed it in a couple other key parts of my application to chip away at execution times. Your explanation re-enforces what his answer implied, and expands on a few things I missed... and mostly I appreciate the effort you put into it. Thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaOlson your welcome. If you found it helpful, please UpVote the answer too ;-)